# Python Azure Funtion - Emptying out an append blob

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I've been creating a timer trigger function that processes some text and saves that text to an append blob every trigger.

What I want it to do is empty the append blob each time the timer triggers, so only new data is appended to the blob. Currently I have the following code at the start of my function:

```
blobServiceClient =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTIONSTRING)
containerClient = blobServiceClient.get_container_client(CONTAINER)

blobClient = containerClient.get_blob_client("test.log")
blobClient.upload_blob("",overwrite=True, blob_type='AppendBlob')
```

I figured this would overwrite the previous version of the append blob, but in practice my append blob keeps the old data and just appends the new data when the timer goes off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not certain why my code didn't want to work, but I found that adding any data to that empty string (including just a space) caused it to finally overwrite when called.